# SVG to PNG convertion issue PHP ImageMagic

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png

I am converting an `.svg` file to `.png` using the php `ImageMagic` library. As a result, I just get a black background without any images in it. Below is the php source code that i am using:

```
<?php
$svg1 = 'heart1-small.svg';
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$svg = file_get_contents($svg1);

$im->readImageBlob($svg);

/*png settings*/
$im->setImageFormat("png24");

$im->writeImage('converted.png');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();

?>
```

Here is [my .svg file](http://haykzprojects.info/svgtopng/heart1-small.svg). 
Any direction will be helpful

Thanks, 
Hayk

Comment: give `$im->setImageFormat("png32");` a try

Comment: Still the same black background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is working, may be your heart1-small.svg file not working properly ...
it working fine ,please use other svg img...
and also once conform your ImageMagic packages in php.ini file.

Comment: Yes, the php code seems to be working fine, what you mean my .svg is not working properly? It does render fine in the browser. Maybe there are some attributes in the .svg that i need to change to make the conversion to .png work?